# Product links redirect to wrong single product url on woo-commerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, redirect

I am using Woo-commerce for an E-Commerce site. All was going right. But now i am facing a serious problem with product url. When someone click on product thumbnail from product list page he/she is redirecting to wrong single product page. This problem is not for all products. But mos of the products are behaving like this.

I searched the solution on google for this, but I didn't found anything.

Can anyone please help me on this. I think this problem is running just after the new update of Woo-Commerce. Below is my E-Commerce site link.

https://www.pet.com.bd/cat-food/

Thanks.

Comment: Every product link worked properly for me. You need to provide more detail (i.e. code) in your question, if you're still experiencing this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I provide the info that not all product behaving like this. But some product are. Please go the the below link.
[https://www.pet.com.bd/cat-food]
And click the below named product from last product row. "Friskies Kitten – Chicken & Fish (400g)"
You will find the problem.

One more thing, actually i don't understand which code should i provide for your better understanding.

Thanks.

Comment: Here is the one url which redirects to another url.
 http://www.pet.com.bd/shop/friskies-kitten-chicken-fish-400g

Can you please remove the not useful vote for me?

Thanks. @mevius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site seems to be working fine on my end.

You can try the following:

1. Deactivate plugins to see if that causes the redirection
2. Try to change your permalinks to default and then back to pretty links
3. Relist the product (delete and remake)
4. Check your htaccess file (some plugins might edit this and cause errors)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your solutions except Relist the product. But nothing changed. I will try the Relist product option soon. And i will notify you.

Comment: Can you send me the specific links of the products that redirect?

Comment: Heap of course. Below is the one link which redirects to another url.
 http://www.pet.com.bd/shop/friskies-kitten-chicken-fish-400g

Comment: Try to manually edit the permalink and see if that works. Also, you use a seo plugin like yoast?

Comment: I manually edit the permalink and it works. Yes i use Yoast SEO plugin.
But i need the actual solution. Coz there is lot of products in the site. 
Thanks.

Comment: Great that it works!  As for yoast,  Yoast has a feature that redirects urls to new urls.  For example, if you had a page with permalink /contact/ but changed it to /service/, yoast detects that and redirects the old url (/contact/) to /service/.  Somewhere in the settings of yoast you can see which urls are redirected to other urls.  I'm currently not behind a PC so I cannot check it myself for you.

Comment: Last solution I can offer you is to reset your permalinks. Go to settings > permalinks and change them to default. Save it and change it back. No worries, the permalinks will stay the same as before. It sort of a .htaccess reset too.

Comment: I already try the permalink changes option. But it didn't work... @Michael

Comment: Yeap lastly I manually edit the permalink of redirected products. Now it's fine. But still I am finding the cause of this problem. Many many thanks @Michael Vermeulen

Answer (score 0):

Find the product or page that is displayed instead of the correct product. Go to that page or product and change the slug.